# How do I change the external apple logo to any other color by going through terminal instead of opening the case?

Tags: macbook-pro

Is there any way for me to change the color of my new, unibody macbook pro's external apple logo to another color without having to use the little transparencies from canada? I would prefer it be through terminal at least.

Comment: I have seen this first hand, I work with hundreds of MacBooks, and once only once, I saw the apple logo as a red in error.(as in there was an error in boot.)

Answer (score 10):

The glowing Apple logo is lit by the LCD backlight. You cannot control its brightness independently from the screen's brightness, and aside from placing a colored gel between the light and the logo, you cannot change its color.

Comment: an apple expert i work with said he's done it but idk, i might just call his bluff i guess

Comment: Unless he's installed a mini LCD in that location, as some have done, it's impossible. Some people have done an LCD mod, though. http://www.macmod.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=3350&p=22126

Comment: As others have said, I don't see how anyone can adjust it via software.  The light is from the LCD backlight, and that's not something that you can adjust from software (other than the light level).  Go ahead and call his bluff.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is impossible. It's "hard wired." You need to open the case to change the color.

Answer (score 1):

So, Im pretty positive the Apple Logo Is actually a light. When Im booted up in Windows 7, i shut the lid and the light satys on for a sec, regaurdless of the screen. The screen is off but the light is on still for a second though...
So, im pretty sure changing the color makes it at least a little easier...
the older macbooks used to have the logo sharing the same light as the screen.

good luck all